# Где хранить сжатые и обрезанные картинки для пользователей или товаров?

Tags: php, html, ajax, изображения

Сразу прошу прощения если такие вопросы уже задавались. Мне нужен попытаться узнать конкретно как и что.

Вопрос вытек из проблемы, проблема заключается в том что у меня на сайте есть товары и к ним картинки. Картинки разного размера, и отображаться должны не в одинаковом размере. И я сделал вывод картинок но сайт жутко лагает. Загружается быстро - 2 секунды, (возможно медленно так как нет хостинга) но после загрузки товаров с картинками сайт лагает.

Картинки храню вот так (возможно неправильно):

**../../img_product/{id_product}/{много картинок}.jpeg**

И вывожу **некоторые** товары по ajax запросом.
Получаю массив товаров, в каждом из них есть массив картинок.
После с помощи js вывожу товары, и с помощи тега `<img src='../../img_product/{id_product}/{много картинок}.jpeg'>` - вывожу картинку.
Вообще я не уверен правильно я делаю выводя товары массивом с помощи ajax, а так-же более не уверен в выводе картинок. (Картинки нахожу соответствующему товару с помощи php)

Посмотрел на торговые площадки и магазины. И картинки у них сжаты. Почитал про это. Но я одно не могу понять, как мне сжимать картинку и так-же выводить в `<img src>`? Получается сжатые картинки где то должны хранится. Можно решить проблему например перед загрузкой картинки сжать её. Но мне нужно немного по другому. Картинка одна и та-же, но отображается она везде по другому, т.е где то она маленькая а где то она большая, где то обрезанная и т.д.

**Получается мне нужно хранить сжатые и обрезанные картинки в специальных папках? Или как то можно при выводе их обрезать и отобразить, но не хранить. Прошу помочь!**

Comment: Обычно для этого используется препроцессинг, где, к примеру, у вас есть картинка товара A.jpeg, и её вариации, сделанные для разных размеров - A_128x128.jpeg, A_256x256.jpeg и т.д. Препроцессинг можно делать на лету, либо после загрузки изображений по расписанию.

Comment: Тут много ньюансов и тонкостей может быть, для начала нужно понимать, используете ли вы cms или php-фреймворк на сайте или вы сайт полностью руками написали. Также, вы могли бы указать какого размера у вас картинки, сколько они весят (примеры). Существуют разные сервисы для сжатия изображений, например, Squoosh. Также, нужно понимать, целесообразно ли использовать аякс запрос, сколько времени занимает запрос, объем данных в запросе. Причиной лагов могут быть не картинки, а что-то еще. Опять же сколько товаров отображается, может стоит сделать пагинацию и т.д.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov спасибо за ответ. Такие имя файлов на некоторых сайтах я как раз таки и видел. Буду изучать. Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: @freestyle_HD спасибо за ответ! Сайт написан с нуля полностью. Картинка размера должна 680x476, и картинки разные, весят по разному. И мне  нужно в зависимости где отображается картинка менять размер, где то что то вырезать, а где то сжимать. Что бы например большая картинка в другом блоке была маленькой и весила бы мало. 

Ajax запросы я вызываю только после прокрутки страницы вниз. И раньше я использовал везде для товаров одну и ту-же картинку, а теперь у каждого товара она своя, и после этого появились лаги. Я пробовал вставлять gif что бы проверить из-за картинок ли лагает или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Получается мне нужно хранить сжатые и обрезанные картинки в специальных папках?**

Да.

**Или как то можно при выводе их обрезать и отобразить, но не хранить.**

В этом случае новые картинки будут генерироваться каждый раз при посещении юзером страницы. Представьте, что сайт посетят одновременно 1000 или больше людей или ботов. В лучшем случае это сильно увеличит нагрузку на сервер. А также увеличит время загрузки страницы.

Чтоб не обрезать все картинки вручную, можно использовать сторонние ресурсы, например, tinypng с использованием API.

Либо написать самому скрипт, который сам отрезайзит картинки в нужном разрешении и формате.

Если нужно выводить картинки разного разрешения для разных экранов, стоит использовать тег [picture](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture), он позволяет указывать, при каких параметрах экрана какие картинки надо выводить и автоопределяет поддерживаемость новых форматов картинок - webp, jp2 и тому подобное.

Comment: Спасибо за большой ответ! 
И спасибо за подсказку `Если нужно выводить картинки разного разрешения для разных экранов`
Все таки как вы сказали что это делает нагрузку на сервер, то думаю мне стоит перед загрузкой сжимать или обрезать картинки.